# How to use OpenGL in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode, opengl-es

I am trying to figure out how to use OpenGL in Xcode five but I cannot figure it out. Is there a relatively good tutorial out there to help with this? I am not looking for the best opinions. I am just looking for a list of some that might help. I have found a couple but they seem to be outdated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3664/opengl-tutorial-for-ios-opengl-es-2-0) will give you a basic tutorial in how to get started on OpenGLES 2.0 on iOS.

It goes over the basic principles of vertex and fragment shaders. It also goes through the creation of objects, and some basic animations.